# Does continuous image of a pseudocompact space attain its bounds?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $X$ be a topological space and any continuous function $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is bounded i.e. $X$ is a pseudocompact topological space.Does it necessarily imply that any continuous real valued function on $X$ attains its supremum and infimum also?If not,can someone provide me a counterexample?

It is clear that if $X$ is compact,then $f(X)$ is compact and hence $f$ is bounded and attains its bounds.But we may find spaces $X$ which are pseudocompact but yet not compact.In that case,this argument fails.That makes me search for an example as mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ is pseudocompact, and $f: X \to Y$ is continuous and onto, $Y$ is also pseudocompact (if $g: Y \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, $g \circ f$ is continuous on $X$ to $\Bbb R$ so bounded, and hence so is $g$).

So if $X$ is pseudompact and $f: X \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, $f[X]$ is a pseudocompact subspace of $\Bbb R$. But for *metric spaces*, pseudocompactness and compactness are equivalent. So $f[X]$ is compact in $\Bbb R$ and so has a maximum and a minimum, ergo $f$ attains its bounds.

Direct proof idea: if $f[X]$ were not closed and $p \in \overline{f[X]}\setminus f[X]$, consider the map $g: X \to \Bbb R$ defined by $\frac{1}{|p-f(x)|}$ which is then continuous and unbounded on $X$. So $f[X]$ is closed and boundedness of $f[X]$ says that $\sup f[X]$ exists and closedness of $f[X]$ implies $\sup f[X] \in f[X]$ etc.